# SQL query new column attachment of string display

Tags: sql, sql-server

With the results of column Name in my query, I want to represent new column TypeName. If the length of name is 6 characters, then "Name alt" should be written in column typename. if the name has 10 characters, then the string "Name new" should be written.

I have the following query

```
Select Name
From tabelle where Status like 'New'
```

Now I get the table name displayed

Comment: This looks like homework to me. You really should be trying this on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `CASE` statement:

```
Select Name,
  case len(Name)
    when 6 then 'Name alt'
    when 10 then 'Name new'
  end typename
From tabelle where Status like 'New'
```

If by `'Name alt'` and `'Name new'` you mean that `Name` should be concatenated with `'alt'` and `'New'` then:

```
Select Name,
  case len(Name)
    when 6 then Name + ' alt'
    when 10 then Name + ' new'
  end typename
From tabelle where Status like 'New'
```

Comment: if i try your example, i get the following errors ```LENGTH' is not recognized as the name of an integrated function.```

Comment: @Maeva I guess you are not using MySql but SQL Server. See my edited answer

Comment: I use sql server. and concat??

Comment: What about concat()? Which version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: Error: CONCAT' is not recognized as the name of an integrated function.

Comment: SQL-Server Version 14.0.17x

Comment: If your version is before 2012 see my edited answer.

Comment: Version  V17.9.1